# saslauthd + PostFix producing password verification and authentication errors

Tags: postfix, sasl, saslauthd

So I'm trying to setup PostFix while using SASL (Cyrus variety preferred, I was using dovecot earlier but I'm switching from dovecot to courier so I want to use cyrus instead of dovecot) but I seem to be having issues. Here are the errors I'm receiving:

```
==> mail.log <==
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: ipname[xx.xx.xx.xx]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure

==> mail.info <==
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: ipname[xx.xx.xx.xx]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure

==> mail.warn <==
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Aug 10 05:11:49 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[779]: warning: ipname[xx.xx.xx.xx]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

I tried

```
$testsaslauthd -u xxxx -p xxxx
0: OK "Success."
```

So I know that the password/user I'm using is correct. I'm thinking that most likely I have a setting wrong somewhere, but can't seem to find where. Here is my files.

Here is my main.cf for postfix:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
myorigin = /etc/mailname

# This is already done in /etc/mailname
#myhostname = crazyinsanoman.xxxxx.com

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
#biff = no


# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
#append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# Relay smtp through another server or leave blank to do it yourself
#relayhost = smtp.yourisp.com

# Network details; Accept connections from anywhere, and only trust this machine
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
inet_interfaces = all
#mynetworks_style = host

#As we will be using virtual domains, these need to be empty
local_recipient_maps =
mydestination =

# how long if undelivered before sending "delayed mail" warning update to sender
delay_warning_time = 4h
# will it be a permanent error or temporary
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
# how long to keep message on queue before return as failed.
# some have 3 days, I have 16 days as I am backup server for some people
# whom go on holiday with their server switched off.
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
# max and min time in seconds between retries if connection failed
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
# how long to wait when servers connect before receiving rest of data
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
# how many address can be used in one message.
# effective stopper to mass spammers, accidental copy in whole address list
# but may restrict intentional mail shots.
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
# how many error before back off.
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
# how many max errors before blocking it.
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12


# Requirements for the HELO statement
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
# Requirements for the sender details
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
# Requirements for the connecting server
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
# Requirement for the recipient address
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
# require proper helo at connections
smtpd_helo_required = yes
# waste spammers time before rejecting them
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# not sure of the difference of the next two
# but they are needed for local aliasing
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
# this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/vmail
# this is for the mailbox location for each user
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
# and this is for aliases
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
# and this is for domain lookups
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
# this is how to connect to the domains (all virtual, but the option is there)
# not used yet
# transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport.cf

# Setup the uid/gid of the owner of the mail files - static:5000 allows virtual ones
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

inet_protocols=all

# Cyrus SASL Support
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = xxxxx.com

#######################
## OLD CONFIGURATION ##
#######################
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = crazyinsanoman.xxxxx.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
#mailbox_size_limit = 0
#recipient_delimiter = +
#html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
message_size_limit = 30720000
#virtual_alias_domains =
##virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
##luser_relay = webmaster
#smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
#smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
#virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
#virtual_maildir_extended = yes
#proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
#virtual_transport = dovecot
#dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Here is my master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
#dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

Here is what I'm using for /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

```
log_level: 7
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
pwcheck_method: auxprop
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: xxxxx
sql_passwd: xxxxx
sql_database: maildb
sql_select: select crypt from users where id = '%u'
```

As you can see I'm trying to use mysql as my authentication method. The password in 'users' is set through the 'ENCRYPT()' function.

I also followed the methods found in http://www.jimmy.co.at/weblog/?p=52 in order to redo /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd as that seems to be a lot of people's problems, but that didn't help at all.

Also, here is my /etc/default/saslauthd

```
START=yes

DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"

NAME="saslauthd"

# Which authentication mechanisms should saslauthd use? (default: pam)
#
# Available options in this Debian package:
# getpwent  -- use the getpwent() library function
# kerberos5 -- use Kerberos 5
# pam       -- use PAM
# rimap     -- use a remote IMAP server
# shadow    -- use the local shadow password file
# sasldb    -- use the local sasldb database file
# ldap      -- use LDAP (configuration is in /etc/saslauthd.conf)
#
# Only one option may be used at a time. See the saslauthd man page
# for more information.
#
# Example: MECHANISMS="pam"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
```

I had heard that potentially changing MECHANISM to MECHANISMS="mysql" but obviously that didn't help as is shown by the options listed above and also by trying it out anyway in case the documentation was outdated.

So, I'm now at a loss... I have no idea where to go from here or what steps I need to do to get this working =/ Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Here is the error that is coming from auth.log ... I don't know if this will help at all, but here you go:

```
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql auxprop plugin using mysql engine
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: begin transaction
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin create statement from userPassword user xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin doing query select crypt from users where id = 'user@xxxxxx.com';
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin create statement from cmusaslsecretPLAIN user xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin doing query select crypt from users where id = 'user@xxxxxx.com';
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: commit transaction
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: begin transaction
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin create statement from userPassword user xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin doing query select crypt from users where id = 'user@xxxxxx.com';
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin create statement from cmusaslsecretPLAIN user xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin doing query select crypt from users where id = 'user@xxxxxx.com';
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: commit transaction
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin Parse the username user@xxxxxx.com
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin try and connect to a host
Aug 11 17:19:56 crazyinsanoman postfix/smtpd[9503]: sql plugin trying to open db 'maildb' on host '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to get. Do you want authenticate users via mysql or saslauthd?

Comment: I had assumed the authentication would go to mysql through saslauthd. From your question I assume that was a wrong assumption. I'd personally want the method that is considered more secure, but would not require user accounts to be created on the server itself. Does that help?

Comment: (Wouldn't let me edit comment) - I'm actually ok with creating accounts. Security would be my primary concern, but I don't know much in this realm unfortunately =/

Answer (score 1):

cyrus-sasl can directly connect to mysql server, there is no need to use saslauthd.

```
# yum info cyrus-sasl-sql
Installed Packages
Name        : cyrus-sasl-sql
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.1.23
Release     : 13.el6_3.1
Size        : 26 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : SQL auxprop support for Cyrus SASL
URL         : http://asg.web.cmu.edu/sasl/sasl-library.html
License     : BSD
Description : The cyrus-sasl-sql package contains the Cyrus SASL plugin which supports
            : using a RDBMS for storing shared secrets.
```

But as far as I know, mysql module of cyrus-sasl can't work with crypted password, moreover you can't use CRAM-MD5/DIGEST-MD5 with crypted password, the password should stored in plaintext.

So as I can see you could try 3 things

1. Find patch for cyrus-sasl that would work with crypted password and use cyrus-sasl-sql module. But in such case forget for CRAM-MD5/DIGEST-MD5
2. Store password in plaintext and use only strong authentication methods like CRAM-MD5/DIGEST-MD5 over encrypted connection imaps (993)/pop3s (995).
3. Use [pam-mysql](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-mysql/) and crypt options

In such case your smtpd.conf should looks like

```
pwcheck_method: auxprop
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_usessl: yes
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: localhost
sql_user: postfix
sql_passwd: postfix
sql_database: postfix
sql_select: select password from mailbox where username = '%u@%r'
log_level: 3
```

You can get more info about crypted password [here](http://pieps.org/cyrus/). Also you could try to build cyrus-sasl with patch from my [personal site](http://storage.sys-adm.org.ua/cyrus-sasl-crypt-password-linux.tar.bz2)

**Note**

CRAM-MD5 are DIGEST-MD5 are Challenge-Response authentication mechanisms (indeed CRAM is short for Challange-Response Authentication Mechanism), plain-text passwords have to be supplied to the instance that handles authentication communication with the user (that is, the SASL client library), rather than the authenticator (the server). Therefore, it is not possible to use PAM with these mechanisms and then you need to configure Cyrus-SASL to have "SQL" auxprop plugin with MySQL support and specify "auxprop" for the preferred password checking method.

Comment: So I changed my smtpd.conf file to what you showed above (minus sql_usessl as I'm not setup with SSL yet and I changed log_level to 7) but I'm still not able to get it to work. Your help was slightly confusing though.  From the sounds of it, Option #3 is going to be the best bet as I don't want plaintext passwords. I was also kind of lost with your explanation of CRAM/DIGEST... Also, I'm thinking most likely I need to stick with 'ENCRYPT' as that's how it's configured in master.cf under the submission section (2nd non commented line). Thanks for your help btw

Comment: [Also, I just added the errors I'm getting from auth.log to hopefully help out]